# Ag-grid: how to get data after it's been filtered?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/972

It was once solved by the above link. But in the 22-MAY-2017 change log by Ag-grid, it says " AG-471: All the events are now asynchronous. afterFilterChanged event dropped."

How do we get the filtered data now?

I'm using Ag-grid with Angular 4.

Comment: Is your question about how to get the data? Or is it about how to know when the grid has finished filtering? Or both?

Comment: @JarodMoser  just for filtering, is the only option to use .gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to filterChanged, it should hook you up just after the filter data has been updated